# Find all instances of a string where the line doesn't begin with a comment character?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm doing a Find in Files for a few strings; `"V1.10"`, `"V1.01A"`, `"V1.2"`

I'd like to find all instances of those values (fine if I have to run 3 different searches) **except for** lines that start with `'` or `//`. Anyone know how to do this?

I'm surprised there's no built-in "Ignore comments" checkbox that works off the file extension.

Something along the lines of `^[']["V1.10"]` but that's not correct at all...

Edit;

Using updated Answer the only result I get now is this:

```
If (mCheckSpecialChar(pStrval, "<?*^%$>#&;:,\()""!`~<>=|%{}[]|") = False) Then ' the bad characters that are not allowed in the first name field for Version V1.10
```

Answer (score 2):

use this expression: `^[^'/].*v1\.10[^.A-Z]`

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `[^'/]` checks whether it doesn't start with comment characters
- `\.` you need to escape "." otherwise it would match any character (e.g. v1010)

This will highlight your search term, but also everything before it in the same line. Notepad++ uses POSIX REGEX which unfortunately doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to have actually returned even *more* results than I was looking for, but still informative so I upvoted it but didn't mark as an answer. Thanks either way.

Comment: please post the unwanted answers and I'll amend my code to avoid them.

Comment: `'9/4/2012 - Added a check to each condition for first and last name fields to escape and allow the special characters for V1.10.0`

Comment: `'This was done to allow special characters for QI V1.10.0`

Comment: `'            '********************V1.10.1***************************`

Comment: Just a few examples.

Comment: I've amended the regular Expression to exclude cases when version number is longer than required (V1.10.1, V1.10A)

Comment: Please post your comments here as an edit to your  main question